# Redirigir a Finalizar Compra si Vendido Individualmente no se cumple

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Como pone en el título, querría redirigir a la página de finalizar compra en Woocommerce en el caso de que un producto tenga marcado el "vendido individualmente" y se añada una segunda unidad.

En el archivo class-wc-cart.php aparece el siguiente código donde imagino que debo editar el resultado del If en el caso de que se cumpla pero no se bien bien como hacer la redirección en el caso de que sea la segunda vez que añaden el producto.

```html
if ( $product_data->is_sold_individually() ) {
    $quantity      = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_sold_individually_quantity', 1, $quantity, $product_id, $variation_id, $cart_item_data );
    $found_in_cart = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_sold_individually_found_in_cart', $cart_item_key && $this->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ]['quantity'] > 0, $product_id, $variation_id, $cart_item_data, $cart_id );

    if ( $found_in_cart ) {
     /* translators: %s: product name */
     throw new Exception( sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', wc_get_cart_url(), __( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ), sprintf( __( 'You cannot addd another "%s" to your cart.', 'woocommerce' ), $product_data->get_name() ) ) );
    }
   }
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

como dice César, podrías olímpicamente poner:

```
if ( $found_in_cart ) {
  header('Location: /cart/');
}
```

Pero la gracia sería introducir ese comportamiento sin tocar woocommerce dado que ese approach significa que en la siguiente actualización vas a perder tu código.

Primero, el método `add_to_cart` se llama en la clase `WC_Form_Handler` (`class-wc-form-handler.php`). Pero hay que bucear un poco para entender el flujo.

Cuando  WC_Form_Handler se inicializa agrega una acción:

```
    add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( __CLASS__, 'add_to_cart_action' ), 20 );
```

No me preguntes desde dónde se gatilla después esa acción porque WooCommerse es críptico en este aspecto. Seguramente en alguna parte hay un `do_action($action.'_cart_action')`, o algo igual de misterioso, de manera que uno busca por el nombre del método y no aparece nada, y de paso mirando el código tampoco se entiende qué hace cada parte.

Como sea, el método estático `WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action` va a recibir un request que contiene al menos el ID del producto. Con éste determina el tipo (variable, agrupado, simple) y según eso delega a otra función.  Por ejemplo si es un producto simple, dice:

```
$was_added_to_cart = self::add_to_cart_handler_simple( $product_id );
```

Y eso te permite saber si se agregó al carrito o no. Si no se agregó, por la razón que sea, el método no devuelve nada (bonita práctica) sino que en algún momento encoló el cuadrito donde te informa el error en el contenido que se va a dibujar en la respuesta.

El método `add_to_cart_handler_simple` (y todos los demás handlers, a grandes rasgos) son los que llaman finalmente a `WC_Cart->add_to_cart` que es la que tú quieres intervenir.

```
private static function add_to_cart_handler_simple( $product_id ) {
    $quantity          = empty( $_REQUEST['quantity'] ) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['quantity'] ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.NonceVerification.NoNonceVerification
    $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity );

    if ( $passed_validation && false !== WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity ) ) {
        wc_add_to_cart_message( array( $product_id => $quantity ), true );
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Que se puede simplificar en:

```
return WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity );
```

Como tú mismo viste en tu pregunta, `WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity )` retorna verdadero o falso. Si en medio ocurrió la excepción que se gatilla cuando el producto se vende sólo por una unidad, esa excepción se pierde en `add_to_cart` y a cambio se dibuja el cuadro de error.

## Mi solución sería

**1.- Evitar que se llame a `WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action`**

Eso lo harías metiendo en el `functions.php` de tu theme:

```
remove_action('wp_loaded', ['WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_action'], 20);
```

Pero ya que quitaste esa acción, hay que

**2. reemplazar la acción removida por otra similar**

o sino el carrito perderá su comportamiento. Pensemos entonces que declaras una función (sería mejor una clase, pero no nos compliquemos) que recibe el mismo tipo de entrada que la que acabas de quitar

```
function add_to_cart_interceptor($url = false) {
    ...tu propia lógica...
}
```

En "tu propia lógica", al igual que en la función original, puedes obtener el producto de antemano:

```
$product_id        = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) ) );
$product_data    = wc_get_product( $product_id );
```

Ahora puedes meter directamente la comprobación que se hacía en WC_Cart->add_to_cart y que pusiste en tu pregunta, pero redirigiendo a gusto.

```
   if ( $product_data->is_sold_individually() ) {
     $quantity = apply_filters( ...);
     $found_in_cart = apply_filters( ...);
     if ( $found_in_cart ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_cart_url() );
        exit;
     }
   }
```

Si no ocurre esa condición, puedes

**3.- devolverle el control al handler original.**

Y eso significa simplemente un llamado manual a `WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action($url);`

## En resumen

Saltándonos las validaciones **sólo para efectos del ejemplo** vamos a decir que al añadir un producto al carrito se envía una petición POST que contiene

```
[
  quantity: 1
  add-to-cart: 12345  // id del producto
]
```

En tu implementación real sí debes poner lo que contienen los métodos originales, o te van a inyectar código más que rápido.

(nota: por la manera en que se declara, hay muchos flujos en los que entrará a la función, así que tengo que comprobar que me están mandando un id de producto en `$_REQUEST['add-to-cart'];`

```
// functions.php
// Quito el hook original
remove_action('wp_loaded', ['WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_action'], 20);

// declaro una nueva función para manejarlo
function add_to_cart_interceptor($url = false) {
   // Si no es una petición de añadir al carrito, me salgo 
   if (!isset($_REQUEST['add-to-cart']) ||
    !isset($_REQUEST['quantity']) ||
    !is_numeric(wp_unslash($_REQUEST['add-to-cart']))) {
    return;
   }
   $product_id =  intval($_REQUEST['add-to-cart']);
   $quantity = intval($_REQUEST['quantity']);
   $product_data    = wc_get_product( $product_id );

   $cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id);

   // Verificas si el producto ya está en el carrito:
   $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $cart_id );

   // Aquí verificas la compra unitaria
   if ( $product_data->is_sold_individually() ) {
      $found_in_cart = $cart_item_key && WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ]['quantity'] > 0;
      if ( $found_in_cart ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_cart_url() );
        exit;
      }
   }

   // Si no cayó en la condición de arriba, devuelvo el flujo al original:
   WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action($url);

}
// agrego mi propio hook
add_action('wp_loaded', 'add_to_cart_interceptor', 20);
```

Hay otros flujos involucrados aquí, que no voy a abordar porque la respuesta ya se alargó, pero por ejemplo la persona podría añadir al carrito via ajax, y en ese caso te llevaría a la vista individual con el cuadrito de advertencia. Ahí habría que meter otro interceptor para el flujo ajax.

Éxito!

Answer (score 0):

Para redirigir en php puedes utilizar la función [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).
Puedes utilizarla de la siguiente manera:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```